# VBA Code not consolidating all duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I hope you can help. I have a piece of code and it works relatively well.

What it does is it allows a user to click on a command button which opens up a dialog box. The user then selects another excel sheet, then the code identifies duplicates consolidates these duplicates creating a new row of data with the earliest available start date and latest available end date and then deletes the duplicates

So in Pic 1 you can see the selected sheet has duplicate entries and multiple start and end dates for these duplicate entries

Pic 1

[image]

Pic 2 shows the sheet after the code has executed

[image]

You can see in Pic 2 that the duplicates have been consolidated and a row of data with the earliest start date and latest end date is left

Agnholt Jørgen Steen is correct

Andersen Anders Nyboe is correct

But it only works if the duplicates are directly under eachother if they are not as in the case with

Christensen Tove and Christensen Trine Tang my code is unable to identify the duplicates and it does not consolidate or work the dates.

Can my code be amended to fix this issue of duplicates not being directly underneath each other?

My code is below as always and all help is greatly appreciated.

MY CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()


    Dim strFileName     As String
    Dim wkb             As Workbook
    Dim wks             As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim r               As Long

    MsgBox "Select Denmark File" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For r = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        ' Identify Duplicate
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 1) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 2) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 2) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 3) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 3) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 4) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 4) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 5) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 5) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 6) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 6) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 7) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 7) Then
           ' Update Start Date on Previous Row
        If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 8)) < CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 8)) Then
         wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) = wks.Cells(r, 8)
        End If
        ' Update End Date on Previous Row
        If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 9)) > CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 9)) Then
        wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) = wks.Cells(r, 9)
        End If
            ' Delete Duplicate
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So i have amended the code to sort Column B but it still leave duplicates

my Code with the sort added is below again any help is greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
Sub Open_Workbook_Dialog()


    Dim strFileName     As String
    Dim wkb             As Workbook
    Dim wks             As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow         As Long
    Dim r               As Long

    MsgBox "Select Denmark File" '<--| txt box for prompt to pick a file

        strFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*") '<--| Opens the file window to allow selection

    Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    lastRow = wks.UsedRange.Rows.Count

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    .Unprotect
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range("A1").Resize(79, lastcol).Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With

    For r = lastRow To 3 Step -1
        ' Identify Duplicate
        If wks.Cells(r, 1) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 1) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 2) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 2) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 3) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 3) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 4) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 4) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 5) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 5) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 6) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 6) _
        And wks.Cells(r, 7) = wks.Cells(r - 1, 7) Then
           ' Update Start Date on Previous Row
        If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 8)) < CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 8)) Then
         wks.Cells(r - 1, 8) = wks.Cells(r, 8)
        End If
        ' Update End Date on Previous Row
        If CDate(wks.Cells(r, 9)) > CDate(wks.Cells(r - 1, 9)) Then
        wks.Cells(r - 1, 9) = wks.Cells(r, 9)
        End If
            ' Delete Duplicate
            Rows(r).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code removes duplicates that are one after another. Those duplicates don't touch, thus aren't deleted.
This way of doing is faster (linear and not quadratic like normal duplicate finding code) but does not work if some duplicates don't touch)

Solution : You should sort the table (with regard to all columns, not just the first one) before running the code. This way duplicates will always touch.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sort which other columns and how alphabetically?

Comment: when you sort you can say you only sort first column, or you sort with lower priority columns. If the first column values are equal, second one is checked & so on

Comment: Hi Pierre. I manually sorted Column B alphabetically then ran the code and it seems to work. Do you have any VBA that alphabetically sorts columns that I can plug into my code?

Comment: You can just use this :  http://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/numbers-2/basics/dialog-sort-listdropped-excel2016.png  (I do have this code but I'm not really allowed to send over professionally made code ;-) )

Comment: ah ok. No problem.:-) I am sure there is some code on here i can leverage.